# Beam/Dataflow: How to trigger results early in a SlidingWindow without losing data?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have three events coming in from PubSub, and I want to join them on a common key, ideally without losing any data. I started out using `beam.window.SlidingWindows(10, 5)` - two sliding windows of 5 seconds each to ensure I got all the events (duplicates are fine in my use case). This worked for getting 100% of the data to join, but the latency was very high, with an average of 35 seconds to join the data. So I decided to experiment with triggers. Setting a trigger of  `beam.transforms.trigger.AfterProcessingTime(1)` was much faster, with an average latency of 3 sec. However, I'm only joining 70% of my data now. I was expecting this code to join the data it could early, while the window would still fire once the watermark passed the sliding window time. How can I fire some of the data early without losing the data that comes later?

```
        event_1_window = (
            event_1
            | beam.Map(lambda r: (r['requestTXID'], r))
            | "Event 1 Window" >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.SlidingWindows(10, 5),
                                                             trigger=beam.transforms.trigger.AfterProcessingTime(1),
                                                             accumulation_mode=beam.transforms.trigger.AccumulationMode.ACCUMULATING
                                                             ))

        event_2_window = (
            event_2
            | beam.Map(lambda r: (r['requestTXID'], r))
            |
            "Event 2 window" >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.SlidingWindows(10, 5),
                                                trigger=beam.transforms.trigger.AfterProcessingTime(1),
                                                accumulation_mode=beam.transforms.trigger.AccumulationMode.ACCUMULATING
                                                ))

        joined = (
            [event_1_window, event_2_window]
            | "Join" >> beam.CoGroupByKey()
            ....
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked with triggers much myself, but it could be that your trigger is only triggered once (see docstring in the [official repo](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/25f9a28596c4a725461b8d3000f9fd3d6c87ad45/sdks/python/apache_beam/transforms/trigger.py#L374)). You might want to confirm this via logging.

If I remember correctly, you have to add a repeatedly triggering, e.g.

```
from apache_beam.transforms.trigger import Repeatedly, AfterProcessingTime

beam.WindowInto(
  beam.window.SlidingWindows(10, 5),
  trigger=Repeatedly(AfterProcessingTime(1)),
  accumulation_mode=beam.transforms.trigger.AccumulationMode.ACCUMULATING
)
```

or other [composite trigger types](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#other-composite-triggers).